# Meaning of a Clifford Geertz quote about the western conception of the individual

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, quotations

Please, explain what the following quotation from Clifford Geertz means:

> The Western conception of the person as a bounded, unique, more or less integrated motivational and cognitive universe; a dynamic center of awareness, emotion, judgment, and action organized into a distinctive whole and set contrastively both against other such wholes and against a social and natural background is, however incorrigible it may seem to us, a rather peculiar idea within the context of the world's cultures.

Clifford Geertz (1974). "From the Native's Point of View": On the Nature of Anthropological Understanding". Bulletin of the American Academy of Arts and Sciences 28:1, p.31.

Specifically I have a hard time understanding the following,

"and action organized into a distinctive whole and set contrastively both against other such wholes and against a social and natural background is, however incorrigible it may seem to us, a rather peculiar idea within the context of the world's cultures."

I understand what the author is trying to convey since I know the context, but I cannot understand exactly that last part of the passage. Please, I want a rewording of that last part.

Comment: May I suggest this belongs not to Learners, but at least to English Language & Usage if not to Literature or Philosophy?

Comment: *I understand what the author is trying to convey since I know the context* - this might be useful information to include in the question, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

In the last part of the passage, the writer is saying that the western concept of the person with distinct action organized in a group (whole) that contrast with other groups in a social and natural setting is a unique concept different than other cultures of the world.